# can't find "WhatsApp Web" on my iPhone

Tags: whatsapp.app

I am trying to set up WhatsApp on my computer (Mac running OS X El Capitan version 10.11.6).  I am told to "select WhatsApp Web" in my iPhone settings.  But there is no "WhatsApp Web" anywhere.  The iPhone is running iOS 11.3.

Answer (score 3):

- Browse to https://web.whatsapp.com/. You should see something like the following, with a QR code at right:

  [image]
- Open WhatsApp on your phone
- Go to Settings->WhatsApp Web/Desktop
- Scan QR code with your phone

Comment: Yeah, there is no "WhatsApp Web" on my phone...

Comment: @jeffbernstein It‘s within the WhatsApp app. If it doesn‘t show up there maybe you need to update WhatsApp.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered on 'WhatsApp Messenger Version 2.18.380' is that when you click on the three dotted line, 'Whatsapp Web' is on there as an option. So, you don't need to go into Settings.
Once you are on there, Scan your QR Code.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot so it becomes more obvious which dotted line is relevant here?

Comment: @nohillside they’re answer is about WhatsApp messenger as is not relevant to the question

Comment: @DaniilManokhin you need the app to enable WhatsApp web, so it is relevant. I just don’t see any dotted line in WhatsApp on my phone, that‘s why I‘m curious about details.

Comment: **Whatsapp messenger** they are talking about